# Corda gradle install fail on Windows: "Could not resolve net.i2p.crypto:eddsa:0.2.0"

Tags: corda

When setting up https://github.com/roger3cev/corda-training-template on Windows I get the following stack trace. It appears to be an issue a file name ending in `.crypto`

```
What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':java-source:compileClasspath'.
Could not resolve net.i2p.crypto:eddsa:0.2.0.
Required by:
project :java-source > net.corda:corda-core:1.0.0
Could not resolve net.i2p.crypto:eddsa:0.2.0.
Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/i2p/crypto/eddsa/0.2.0/eddsa-0.2.0.pom'.
Failed to move file 'C:\Users\A57C\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download2832834655657514563bin' into filestore at 'C:\Users\A57C\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.i2p.crypto\eddsa\0.2.0\d2905a940ee7c59e1636e1c3541069ccbbcdf227\eddsa-0.2.0.pom'
Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\A57C\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.i2p.crypto' when creating directory 'C:\Users\A57C\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.i2p.crypto\eddsa\0.2.0\d2905a940ee7c59e1636e1c3541069ccbbcdf227'
Could not resolve net.i2p.crypto:eddsa:0.2.0.
```

How can I successfully import this dependency?

Comment: It sounds like a firewall issue. If you open a browser on the machine where you're having this issue, are you able to access https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/i2p/crypto/eddsa/0.2.0/eddsa-0.2.0.pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct download of eddsa 0.2.0 from MVNRepository resolved the issue: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.i2p.crypto/eddsa/0.2.0

```
mvn install:install-file "-Dfile=eddsa-0.2.0.jar" "-DgroupId=net.i2p.crypto" "-DartifactId=eddsa" "-Dversion=0.2.0" "-Dpackaging=jar"
```

Add`cordaCompile "net.i2p.crypto:eddsa:0.2.0"` to the `build.gradle` in kotlin-source and java-source to import the artifact.